# Does using native Scala methods on Spark RDD's lose out on Spark magic?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm diving into Spark for work and I have a question about how Spark handles certain things.

Say I have an RDD of key -> value pairs: (CustomerID, TotalSpend). If I use .sortBy on the RDD, since .sortBy is a Scala method and not a Spark method, am I missing out on Spark magic?

In other words, to benefit from the distribution that Spark will do, can you only use Spark methods on RDD's? I've seen examples where people will want to do something like: rdd.sortBy(x => x._2) but instead they'll map the rdd first to reverse the tuple members, then use rdd.reduceByKey().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RDD.sortBy`, and everything else to do with RDD comes from Spark, and it not part of the Scala standard library.  There are no standard Scala methods that work with RDD since the entire concept of RDD comes from Spark.

Comment: Duh. Can't believe that didn't occur to me. In my head I had thought that Spark had extended Scala collection functions on to its RDDs. Thanks.